# Как настроить in_array в PHP?

Tags: php

Например, программа:

```
$a=999;
$a1="red";
$b=array(
"777"=>array("kd"=>"34", "um"=>"red"),
"888"=>array("kd"=>"16", "um"=>"yelow")
);
if(in_array($a1,$b[$a]){
echo "I find!";
}else{
echo "No Find!";
};
```

Программа работает, только выдает еще ошибку, что не нашло значения. Как убрать это предупреждение об ошибке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в блокноте свои скрипты пишете? 2 ошибки в синтаксисе нашел

http://ideone.com/rXlVFQ

```
$a=777; 
$a1="red";

$b=array( "777"=>array("kd"=>"34", "um"=>"red"), "888"=>array("kd"=>"16", "um"=>"yelow") );

if (is_array($b[$a]) && in_array($a1,$b[$a])) { 
    echo "I find!"; 
} else { 
    echo "No Find!"; 
}
```

Comment: Извините, немного неправильно вопрос задан. Ошибку выдает, если вместо $a подставить другое значение, которого нет в массиве. При этом No find тоже выдаст вместе с ошибкой.

Comment: @zaryad68gmail, впредь задавайте вопросы четко. Пишите, что за ошибки и т.д. Тут все за вас делать не будут. Исправил http://ideone.com/MblWuu

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь все работает.

Answer (score 0):

Научу плохому: PHP поддерживает один оператор управления ошибками: знак (@). В случае, если он предшествует какому-либо выражению в PHP-коде, любые сообщения об ошибках, генерируемые этим выражением, будут проигнорированы. (взято с php.net)

Comment: не надо так =) как писал об этом товарищ @ua6xh http://hashcode.ru/questions/314886#314889 - вас ждет анальная кара